# Angular 2 - ngFor subnavbar menu doesn't work with CSS

Tags: css, angular

```
.sub-navbar {
  background-color: #002b31;
  height:57px;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 175px;
}
```

> This is my CSS file ,
>
> And this is my HTML file

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default sub-navbar">
        <div *ngFor="let nav of navMenu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                <div *ngIf="nav.link == currentLink">
                    <li *ngFor="let sub of nav.subMenu">
                        <a [routerLink]="[sub.link]">
                            {{sub.name}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here is what it looks like the sub menu because menu is okay / Photo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution :D  - weekend

```
<div class="container-fluid ">
<div class="row">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default sub-navbar">
        <div *ngFor="let nav of navMenu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav " *ngIf="nav.link == currentLink">
                <!--<div *ngIf="nav.link == currentLink" >-->
                    <li *ngFor="let sub of nav.subMenu">
                        <a [routerLink]="[sub.link]">
                            {{sub.name}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <!--</div>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

the problem was in the  tag with the ngIf